# ページネーションを作成していますが、jQueryが上手く設定できません

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

WordPressでサイトを作成しています。
アーカイブページで、ページネーションを入れたいです。

下記サイトの通りにやっていますがうまくいきません。
https://shanabrian.com/web/jquery/pagination.php

実際にやってみると表示されるサイトが１０で、ページネーションのリンクの数も３とか５とかが、理想ですが、１つしかリンク（他のページに飛べる数字のついたリンク）がないなど、（下記写真）
逆に多くのリンク（他のページに飛べる数字のついたリンク）があるが１つの記事しか表示されないなどの、上手く行かないことがあります。

私はjQueryを普段コピペで使うなど、理解が足らないことがあります。

footer.php

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.items').pagination({
        itemElement              : '> div',(ここの設定を＞divにするかdivにするかによて１０表示されたりします。)
        paginationClassName      : 'pagination',
        paginationInnerClassName : 'clearfix',
    
    });
});

$(function() {
    var $sample = $('.item').pagination({
        itemElement              : '> li',
        paginationClassName      : 'pagination',
        paginationInnerClassName : 'clearfix'
    });
 
    $('.item').on('click', function() {
        $sample.movePage(3);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

archive.php

```
  <div class="list-box">
                        <ul class="items">
                            <?php
                            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                            $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                                'post_type'      => 'post', // ページの種類（例、page、post、カスタム投稿タイプ）
                                'paged'          => $paged,
                                'posts_per_page' => 10, // 表示件数
                                'orderby'        => 'date',
                                'order'          => 'DESC'
                            ));
                            if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
                                while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                            ?>
                                    <?php  start ?>
                                         <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
                                             <div class="item">
                                            <article class="blog-list__list-item">  
                                                <div class="blog-list-wrapper-second">
                                                    <?php  start 
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-second">
                                                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                                            <div class="thumbnail-image-second"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 148)); ?></div>
                                                        <?php else : ?>
                                                            <div class="thumbnail-image-second">
                                                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sample4.png" alt="" width="240" height="148" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <?php end ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="blog-item-content">
                                                    <p class="blog-item-day-second"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
                                                    <?php  start  ?>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item">
                                                        <h3 class="blog-item-title">
                                                            <div class="blog-item-title-container">
                                                                <?php
                                                                if (mb_strlen($post->post_title, 'UTF-8') > 20) {
                                                                    $title = mb_substr($post->post_title, 0, 20, 'UTF-8');
                                                                    echo $title . '…';
                                                                } else {
                                                                    echo $post->post_title;
                                                                }?>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php  end ?>
                                                <div class="blog-item-txt">
                                                    <?php start 
                                                    ?>
                                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                    <?php  end 
                                                    ?>
                                                </div>
                                            
                                            </article>
                                            </div> 
                                            <?php break; ?>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>    
                                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                             <div class="item">
                                            <article class="blog-list__list-item">
                                        
                                                <div class="blog-list-wrapper-second">
                                                    <?php start ?>
                                                    <div class="blog-item-thumbnail">
                                                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                                            <div class="thumbnail-image">
                                                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 179)); ?>
                                                            </div>
                                                        <?php else : ?>
                                                            <div class="thumbnail-image">
                                                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sample4.png" alt="" width="240" height="179" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <?php end ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="blog-item-content">
                                                    <p class="blog-item-day-second"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
                                                    <?php  start ?>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item">
                                                        <h3 class="blog-item-title">
                                                            <?php
                                                            if (mb_strlen($post->post_title, 'UTF-8') > 20) {
                                                                $title = mb_substr($post->post_title, 0, 20, 'UTF-8');
                                                                echo $title . '…';
                                                            } else {
                                                                echo $post->post_title;
                                                            }
                                                            ?></h3>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <?php  end 
                                                    ?>
                                                    <?php  start 
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="blog-item-excerpt">
                                                        <?php echo mb_substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 50) . '[...]'; ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <?php  end 
                                                    ?>                 
                                            </article> 
                                           </div>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>    
                                    <?php  end ?>
                                    <?php break; ?>      
                            <?php  endwhile;
                            else :   echo '<div><p>ありません。</p></div>';
                            endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

写真には１０の記事が出ていますが、１つしかページネーションが出ません、
記事の数は合計３０ぐらいはあります。

イメージ説明

何卒宜しくお願いします。

*マルチポストしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/q52djcb3y7id1f
https://qiita.com/keikkkk/questions/3c30295eba3b5ecf02a9

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: functions.phpのファイルに設定した。    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        // 管理画面ではないメインクエリの場合
        if ( is_archive(  ) ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page' ,10 );  // カテゴリーアーカイブで表示したい数
        }
    }
    return $query;
} );の１０という指定をはずすとうまくいくみたいで、この数を指定しなくてもいい方法をいまから探します。

Answer (score 0):

ご思案くださった方々大変、ありがとうございました！！

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) { if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) { // 管理画面ではないメインクエリの場合 if ( is_archive( ) ) { $query->set( 'posts_per_page' , -1 ); // カテゴリーアーカイブで表示したい数 } } return $query; } );
```

-1と指定することで全てを表示させることが出来ます。 上記のコードをfunction.phpに入れることで可能になりました。 また、 paginationClassName : 'pagination',となっているのに、HTMLに.paginationが存在しない。 paginationClassName : 'pagination',としているページネーションが複数設定されているので、衝突してそう。 などの解決と、書きを理解してclass名で指定するなどをすることで、可能になります。 itemsは、適切なクラスを設定した方がいいです